# elastic javaapi regex case insensitive

Tags: java, regex, elasticsearch

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "user.id": {
        "value": "k.*y",
        "case_insensitive": true,
      }
    }
  }
}
```

what is java api equivalent for this example (above query) in elastic docs ?
I can't find a way to add case_insensitive.

```java
QueryBuilders.regexpQuery("user.id", "k.*y")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no Querybuilder in Elasticsearch which supports case insensitive option, you need to Anlayze your field so that it creates a lowercase token and than you the match query which uses the same analyzer on the search term and lowercases the search term, that way you can achieve the case-insensitive search in Elasticsearch.

Note : Default analyzer [standard](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) uses the lowercases the tokens, otherwise you can use the [lower case token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lowercase-tokenfilter.html) in your analyzer and make it work.

**EDIT**: Looks like Elasticsearch recently added the support of `caseInsensitive` param and it was added as part of [this PR](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/61543) which was merged on 25th Aug, 2020 and it looks like it supports ES versions greater than or equal to 7.10.

Comment: But its there in direct json query. So its java client limitation right ?

Comment: @MohitSingh you are on which ES version?

Comment: @MohitSingh pleas see my EDIT, you are correct, its supported in ES JSON query but in code its available only from ES 7.10